# How can ı connect google cloud storage from Colab with different mail

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I connect google cloud storage from Colab with this code

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

**When I use it in this way, the mail I use Colab and the GCP mail must be the same. But I am connecting via a different email. And I am getting error like this.**

[image]

**How can I connect to Cloud Storage with Colab session not having same mail as GCP?**